# Get no of posts inside with a term for a custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

How can i get the no of posts inside a term of a custom taxonomy ? (including the posts that are attached to a child term).

For example i have:

- term (2 posts)
- -child term (2 posts)
- --child child term (1 post)

Right now i'm, doing it like this:

```
$categories = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
foreach ($categories as $categ) {
    print $categ->name.' / '.$categ->count;
}
```

But for "term" i get only 2 posts when i really need to show 5( 2 from "term" and 3 from it's children).

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably have a lot more luck posting this on the [Wordpress Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this: do a standard [`WP_Query` with taxonomy parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your_custom_taxonomy',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'your-parent-term-name',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Get the count
$count = $query->post_count;
```

If you don't know the name(s) of terms within a taxonomy, you can do a query and pass their IDs as an array to `WP_Query`. See [this post on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138270/64331) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I run into few times, and I changed [the code from PatchRanger on bountify](https://bountify.co/need-a-wordpress-function-to-count-the-number-of-posts-in-a-category-with-subcategories#answer_1016) to make it work with taxonomies (so please note this solution is based on his work):

```
function wp_get_term_postcount($term) {
    $count = (int) $term->count;
    $tax_terms = get_terms($term->taxonomy, array('child_of' => $term->term_id));
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $count += wp_get_term_postcount_recursive($tax_term->term_id);
    }
    return $count;
}

function wp_get_term_postcount_recursive($term_id, $excludes = array()) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $tax_term_terms = get_terms($tax_term->name, array(
            'child_of' => $tax_term->term_id,
            'exclude' => $excludes,
        ));
        $count += $tax_term->count;
        $excludes[] = $tax_term->term_id;
        $count += wp_get_term_postcount_recursive($tax_term->term_id, $excludes);
    }
    return $count;
}
```

The recursive function is there to prevent double counting of childs. You can add those two functions inside *functions.php*.

Then update your code to use it:

```
$categories =  get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
foreach($categories as $categ) {
    print  $categ->name.' / 'wp_get_term_postcount($categ);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - i will try it in a few. One question : does the recursive function will increase the loading time or memory consumption when you have lots of terms ?

Comment: Yeah it would just a bit, but not that much as the return of `get_terms` is cached - but note that it's not a persistent cache, so it will just prevent the query to been executed twice on a page load - so when you query for childs on your template it will come from cache as it have been already executed in the recursive function.

Comment: This is neat...but really inefficient.

Comment: @rnevius Yes I saw your answer, it's much more appropriate - I didn't thought of doing this in this way.